# Why isn't my os.rename working?

Tags: python, rename

I'm trying to rename some files, but getting a baffling error*.  When I run this:

```
if os.path.isfile(fullPath):
    print 'fmf exists'
    print fullPath
    print newFilePath
    os.rename(fullPath,newFilePath)
```

I get the following error:

```
fmf exists
(correct fullPath)
(correct newFilePath, ie. destination)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "whatever.py", line 374, in ?
    os.rename(fullPath,newFilePath)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Since I *know* that the file at fullPath exists, I'm baffled by the error.  Of course, newFilePath doesn't exist, because that would be dumb.  Any hints?

Thanks!
Alex

*Aren't they all?

Comment: Have you tried to hard-code the os.rename() with the fullpath and newFilePath that you got ?

Comment: I'm continuously amazed by people who take out what they consider unimportant information but probably isn't. Don't hamstring those trying to help you. By all means hide _sensitive_ information but not the filename in a situation where the OS says it can't find that file :-) At a bare minimum, just replace the sensitve bits: /gov/nsa/keys.txt => /unimportant/company/file.txt

Comment: Um, ok, if this really helps - replace the redacted lines with the following:

/groups/baker/vaughana/Data/10.03.25_Set4_25C/20100325T131243_260hz_gaussian_35msIPI_300s.wav_-10_Cam1/20100325T131243_260hz_gaussian_35msIPI_300s.wav_-10_Cam1.fmf
/groups/baker/vaughana/originalData/20100325T131243_260hz_gaussian_35msIPI_300s.wav_-10_Cam1.fmf

That said, repasting it in made me look at it again and notice that the dest path was wrong, so that's a win.

Comment: `os.path.isfile` introduces an unnecessary race condition compared to trying to perform this operation, catching the exception, and checking the errno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still get the exception if you try to copy to a directory that does not exist.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I had confirmed that the newFilePath didn't exist (as indeed it shouldn't) but the dest directory was wrong as well.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the full inner workings of your code, so here's my two cents worth:

Your newFilePath may contain a directory that doesn't exist. If that is the case, then depending on your operating system, your program is unable to create a file in a directory that doesn't exist. That could be your error.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the poster solved his problem, but I had the same symptom and the cause appeared to be different. The file I was trying to rename had just been created in a subprocess call on the previous line. If I ran my script again, I didn't have the rename problem, since the file had been created in the previous run, but if I deleted the file previously created, I would get the same problem with rename. It seems like os.rename was getting called before the subprocess was completed and the file to be renamed therefore didn't exist yet. I inserted an os.wait() after the subprocess call, and I believe that this has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when my new filename contained forward slashes, which are confused with directory separators in Unix and Linux. For example, renaming a file to "4/27/2015.txt" leads to a directory that doesn't exist and results in "No such file or directory". You can solve this by replacing the forward slashes with any other acceptable character.

Comment: This seems like a valid answer, albeit based on a possibly mistaken premise that the input filenames contain '/' characters.